# Is it possible to always show the placeholder in react-select?

Tags: placeholder, react-select

Currently when I select an option from the dropdown the placeholder disappears. Is there a way to always show it?

Something similar to this? Where "Jobs +" is the placeholder

[image: I'm looking for something like this]